# How to compile the resources.qrc file with pyrcc5

Tags: python, plugins

I am trying to make a plugin for QGIS 3(I am using Windows 10) but before it is created one step before it shows this message :

```
"The resource compiler pyrcc5 was not found in your path. You'll have to manually compile the resources .qrc file with pyrcc5 before installing your plugin".
```

This is a setback because after setting a plugin path in pyqgis it deploys but the plugin says it cannot find the class module.

I have managed to make a plugin but it says error when calling its `classFactory()` method thus i think this is because I fail to compile the pyrcc5.

It brings this error upon after selecting it couldn't load plugin `'remove_feature'` due to an error when calling its `classFactory()` method :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'remove_feature.resources' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 335, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/Users/Arnold Kilaini M/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\remove_feature\__init__.py", line 35, in classFactory
    from .Remove_feature import Remove_feature
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 672, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/Arnold Kilaini M/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\remove_feature\Remove_feature.py", line 29, in 
    from .resources import *
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 672, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'remove_feature.resources'

Python version: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.4.5-Madeira Madeira, 89ee6f6e23 

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/Arnold Kilaini M/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/Arnold Kilaini M/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\bin\python37.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/Arnold Kilaini M/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:\Users\Arnold Kilaini M\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\mmqgis/forms
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the OSGeo4W Shell, run `qt5_env.bat` and `py3_env.bat`.
Then, change the directory to

> C:\Users\Arnold Kilaini M\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\mmqgis".

Run `pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc`

Also, I found the [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260743/how-to-compile-qtdesigner-user-interface-ui-and-resource-qrc-files-with-qg/264377#264377) to a gis.stackexchange question related to yours:

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

With this .bat I don't have any problem aymore.

```
@echo off
SET QGIS_ROOT=C:\GIS\QGIS
call "%QGIS_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat
call "%QGIS_ROOT%"\apps\grass\grass78\etc\env.bat

path %PATH%;%QGIS_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin
path %PATH%;%QGIS_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass78\lib
path %PATH%;C:\GIS\QGIS\apps\Qt5\bin
path %PATH%;C:\GIS\QGIS\apps\Python37\Scripts

set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%QGIS_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%QGIS_ROOT%\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages

set PYTHONHOME=%QGIS_ROOT%\apps\Python37
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%QGIS_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%QGIS_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins

set PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\bin;%PATH%

cmd.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

for Ubuntu users, i tried this and it didn't work out:

```
pb_tool compile
```

also tied to install python-qt5 and Ubuntu 20.04 couldn't find it, then used

```
sudo apt install pyqt5-dev-tool
```

then pb_tool compile and it worked.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out :) - but must be "pyqt5-dev-tools" (plural)